# How can I change a keyboard key foreground image?

Tags: java, android, keyboard

In Android, how can I change a keyboard key foreground image using Java? For example, I want to change the Shift image to a Capslock-on image.

I'm updating my own keyboard app, which is based on the original Soft Keyboard example.

Comment: Are you writing your own input method? Or are you trying to affect input methods written by other developers?

Comment: I'm updating my own keyboard app which is based on the original Soft Keyboard example.